# React Konva: onClick() not firing in functional component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, arrow-functions, konvajs

I am trying to create an `onClick` event on an image in a functional component which is the grand-child of the component where I have my Konva Stage. 
However nothing seems to fire.

I have even tried putting the `onClick` on a `div` in the component with the stage. Still nothing. 
The only way I can handle clicks is if I put an `onMouseDown` on my stage. But that is not practical in this instance, since I need the click to trigger a change in the grandchild component.

Why will nothing trigger?

Here is the code. I have cut away irrelevant code and functions.

Look in the `PanelRect.js` component to find the `onClick()` that is supposed to trigger the `select()` function.

First off, this is the grandparent, with the Konva stage.

***Map.js***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Konva from 'konva';
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from 'react-konva';
import { keyHandler, KEYPRESS } from 'react-key-handler';
import MapRoomRect from './MapRoomRect';
import { PanelRect } from './PanelRect';

const Map = () => {
    return (
        <section className='map'>
            <h1>Projekt X</h1>
            <div className='map_box'>

                <div className='map_box_container' >
                    <div className='map_box_container_stage'>
                        <Stage name='Stage' width={stageWidth} height={stageHeight} onMouseDown={handleStageMouseDown} onKeyPress={handleKeyDown}>
                            <Layer
                                onMouseEnter={handleLayerMouseEnter}
                                onMouseLeave={handleLayerMouseLeave}
                            >

                            <MapRoomRect
                              name='MapRoomRect'
                              draggable
                              visible={false}
                              />

                                <Image name='IconImage' draggable visible={false}/>


                            </Layer>
                        </Stage>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

This is the parent component

***MapRoomRect.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { Rect, Group, Image } from 'react-konva';
import useImage from 'use-image';
import { PanelRect } from './PanelRect';

const MapRoomRect = (props) => {

    return (
        <Group
            name='RoomGroup'
            roomType='RoomType'
            id='0002'
            onDragEnd={() => { }}
            position={{ x: 200, y: 200 }}
            draggable
            visible={false}
            size={{ width: roomSize, height: roomSize }}
        >
            <Rect
                name='RoomGroupBackground'
                size={{ width: roomSize, height: roomSize }}
                opacity={0.3}
                fill='red'
            />
            <PanelRect
                name='PanelGroup'
                onDragEnd={() => { }}
                size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize2 }}
                x={0}
                y={0} />

        </Group>
    )
}

export default MapRoomRect;
```

The child / grand-child component:

***PanelRect.js***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Rect, Group, Image } from 'react-konva';
import useImage from 'use-image';

// Images
import backgroundImage from '../../images/tp6icon.png';
import iconTestImage from '../../images/lo1.png';
import iconTestImage2 from '../../images/lo2.png';
import iconTestImage3 from '../../images/lo3.png';
import iconTestImage4 from '../../images/lo4.png';
import iconTestImage5 from '../../images/lo5.png';

import MapContext from './MapContext';


const PanelRect = (props) => {

      // Hooks
    const [mapState, setMapState] = useState(mapContext);


    let los = [0, 0, 0, 3, 4];
    // Hooks
    const [testImage] = useImage(iconTestImage);
    const [testImage2] = useImage(iconTestImage2);
    const [testImage3] = useImage(iconTestImage3);
    const [testImage4] = useImage(iconTestImage4);
    const [testImage5] = useImage(iconTestImage5);

    var images = [testImage,testImage2,testImage3,testImage4,testImage5];

    // Constants that does not change
    const roomSize = 5;
    const roomSize2 = 7;
    const iconSize = 2;
    const iconSize2 = 2;


    const select = (e) => {
          console.log('Hi! "e" is now: ' + e + ' hmmm');
    }

    return (
        <Group
            name='PanelGroup'
            roomType='PanelType'
            id='0003'
            onDragEnd={() => { }}
            position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            draggable
            size={{ width: roomSize, height: roomSize2 }}
        >
        <Rect
            name='PanelGroupBackground'
            size={{ width: roomSize, height: roomSize2 }}
            opacity={0.9}
            fill='blue'
        />
            <Image name='IconImage' lid='LO1' lo='0' className='imageAnchor' onDragEnd={() => { }} onClick={() => {select()}} image={images[los[0]]} size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize }} draggable={false} x={0} y={0} />
            <Image name='IconImage' lid='LO2' lo='1' className='imageAnchor' onDragEnd={() => { }} onClick={() => {select()}} image={images[los[1]]} size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize }} draggable={false} x={2} y={0} />
            <Image name='IconImage' lid='LO3' lo='2' className='imageAnchor' onDragEnd={() => { }} onClick={() => {select()}} image={images[los[2]]} size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize }} draggable={false} x={0} y={2} />
            <Image name='IconImage' lid='LO4' lo='3' className='imageAnchor' onDragEnd={() => { }} onClick={() => {select()}} image={images[los[3]]} size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize }} draggable={false} x={2} y={2} />
            <Image name='IconImage' lid='LO5' lo='4' className='imageAnchor' onDragEnd={() => { }} onClick={() => {select()}} image={images[los[4]]} size={{ width: iconSize, height: iconSize2 }} draggable={false} x={0} y={4} />


        </Group>
    )
}

export { PanelRect }
```

I don't get any error messages or warnings. It's just that nothing happens when I click. No matter where I put the `onClick()`.

***Edit 7th aug 2019***

I have created a sandbox that shows the problem.

- Click "create red square"
- Click on the red square.
- Click "edit red square"
- Click on the blue square inside
- Click "edit blue square"
- Click on the tiles with numbers on in the blue square.

It is the `onClick()` on these that I want to fire, and get access to the synthetic event object so I can access the target.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-ramanujan-p53b9?fontsize=14

Comment: I built a sandbox with a much simpler version of your component, and could not reproduce. Is anything being logged? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Please create a reproducible demo.

Comment: I built a sandbox of the project. I could definitely cut more away to isolate the incident. But here goes (I have updated the post too with a guide to the sandbox) https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-ramanujan-p53b9?fontsize=14

Comment: I have managed to make an onClick() on the Image "MapImage" that the Map.js returns. And make it call a function that sits in the Map.js file. But i still can't get any of the children or grandchildren to fire any onClick()

Comment: I have also understood, that when I set my initial child element as: visible={true} it is possible to trigger the onClick() on the node. 

But any clone of the initial node will not have any onClick() functionality. 
I guess the question is now: How do I keep my onClick() on nodes that are cloned?